# Can manually save image but not scrape image off site, whats going on?

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping

I have a simple script that can download most any images and store it in a file. However, I have encountered this Chinese website that causes me to download a wrong image?

Here are a few sample images that I attempted to save:
[Image1](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/05269e07/7bd1fc86.png)/ [Image2](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg)/ [Image3](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6def734d/small.jpg)

```
import urllib.request

def Save_Image(url, file_path, file_name):
    full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

url = 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/05269e07/7bd1fc86.png'
file_name = 'Image1'
#!) Manually create an Image1 Folder in the same directory as this script

Save_Image(url,
          'imageFolder/',
           file_name)
```

However, if you try running my script, with the following links, it will download a dummy image. I simply wish to know why this is so? :O

As the title mentioned, I can actually right click and save image, however cannot save it via software. Am I missing something here and are there ways around this?

Comment: `curl 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/05269e07/7bd1fc86.png'` produces a redirect. Your browser takes care of that automatically. `urllib` does not.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back, do you have recommendations to mimic the browsers ability to handle the redirect? I would be more than happy to check it out!

Comment: @Kendas Okay I think to sharpen my conceptual understanding, am I right to say that when i enter the site via cmd using my script, the link redirects me to the dummy image? Is there a way to brute force a 'turn' back to the desired link?

Comment: Have a look at the [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. It also handles redirects. And has a somewhat better overall API.

Comment: For me the URL produces an image that I can only describe as probably the 'dummy image' you're referencing (some hieroglyphics and an url for a help page). Are you sure this image is publicly available? It could be that accessing it requires you to be logged in.

Comment: Can you view this image [link](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6def734d/small.jpg) ? I think you are absolutely spot on wrt redirection. However, Im uncertain as to the specific section of request that would turn back against the redirection. @Kendas , can a checking on history be a solution :O

Comment: On the provided link, I see exactly the same image as before. As an aside, looking at `urllib.request` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), the `urlopen` function _should_ handle redirects.

Comment: @Kendas Alright! Will check that out, your comments have been much appreciated! Will post a solution if I manage to solve it :P

Comment: @Kendas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727860/how-to-brute-force-u-turn-against-a-redirect