# How to brute force 'U-Turn' against a redirect

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

*Hey StackOverFlow,*

I am trying to save some images using the python requests library, however, I have come across a challenge trying to save images from a Chinese website.

*I have 3 sample code snippets to illustrate my problem:*

1. An ideal model situation where I save a simple image
2. Status code:200. Different input and final URLs. Dummy image saved
3. Status code:302. Same input and final URLs. Weird image saved

Sample Images: [Image1/](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg) [Image2/](http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6def734d/small.jpg)

***Functions:***

```
def get_response(url):
    print('Input URL:\n\t %s'%(url))
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response

def get_response_dont_redirect(url):
    print('Input URL:\n\t %s'%(url))
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    return response

def check_response_status(response):
    status = response.status_code
    if status == 200:
        print(('Final URL:\n\t %s')%response.url)
        print('Status Code: %s / OK'%(status))
        return 'ok'
    if status == 302:
        print(('Final URL:\n\t %s')%response.url)
        print('Status Code: %s / Redirected'%(status))
        return 'redirected'
    if status == 404:
        print('Status Code: %s / Access Denied'%(status))
        return 'denied'

def save_image(response, status_code):
    if status_code ==302:
        with open('image_wanted.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image desired under "image_wanted.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)
    elif status_code == 200:
        with open('image_redirect.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image redirected under "image_redirect.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)
    elif status_code == 111:
        with open('image_normal.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image normal under "image_normal.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)

def case_1_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# This is the ideal situation where I can simply download an image')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
def case_2_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# Notice that despite the status code being 200, the input URL and final URL is different ')
    print('\t>I am definitely being redirected')
    print('\t>I get a dummy image from the redirected page')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
def case_3_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# Here I have set the restriction of "allow_redirects=False" yet I get status code:302 ')
    print('\t>Somehow the input and final URL is the same')
    print('\t>The image saved is perpetually loading...')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

***Case 1: Ideal Case***

```
print("\n\n--- Case 1: Ideal ---\n")

url = 'https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/094/514/6000200094514.jpg'
response = get_response(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 111)
case_1_comments()
```

***Case 2: Without 'allow_redirect=False'***

```
print("\n\n--- Case 2: without 'allow_redirects=False' restriction ---\n")

url = 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg'
response = get_response(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 200)
case_2_comments()
```

***Case 3: With 'allow_redirect=False'***

```
print("\n\n--- Case 3: with 'allow_redirects=False' restriction ---\n")

url = 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg'
response = get_response_dont_redirect(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 302)
case_3_comments()
```

If you copy paste my code and run it (See below this question and pip install requests first if you haven't), you will see that case 2 and 3 are pretty weird. My desired goal is to force a return to the input URL and save the image on that page.

I have managed to return to that page as seen in the case 3, but the image for some reason is just a loading screen.

***So I guess my questions are:***

- **Did I actually turn against the redirect?**
- **How do I save the picture I want and not get that loading image?**

***Below is the entire script to run***
*(Please forgive the spaghetti)**:***

```
import requests
def get_response(url):
    print('Input URL:\n\t %s'%(url))
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response

def get_response_dont_redirect(url):
    print('Input URL:\n\t %s'%(url))
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    return response

def check_response_status(response):
    status = response.status_code
    if status == 200:
        print(('Final URL:\n\t %s')%response.url)
        print('Status Code: %s / OK'%(status))
        return 'ok'
    if status == 302:
        print(('Final URL:\n\t %s')%response.url)
        print('Status Code: %s / Redirected'%(status))
        return 'redirected'
    if status == 404:
        print('Status Code: %s / Access Denied'%(status))
        return 'denied'

def save_image(response, status_code):
    if status_code ==302:
        with open('image_wanted.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image desired under "image_wanted.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)
    elif status_code == 200:
        with open('image_redirect.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image redirected under "image_redirect.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)
    elif status_code == 111:
        with open('image_normal.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            print('\nSaving image normal under "image_normal.jpg"...\n')
            f.write(response.content)

def case_1_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# This is the ideal situation where I can simply download an image')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
def case_2_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# Notice that despite the status code being 200, the input URL and final URL is different ')
    print('\t>I am definitely being redirected')
    print('\t>I get a dummy image from the redirected page')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
def case_3_comments():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('#Comments:')
    print('# Here I have set the restriction of "allow_redirects=False" yet I get status code:302 ')
    print('\t>Somehow the input and final URL is the same')
    print('\t>The image saved is perpetually loading...')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')

print("\n\n--- Case 1: Standard procedure ---\n")
url = 'https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/094/514/6000200094514.jpg'
response = get_response(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 111)
case_1_comments()

print("\n\n--- Case 2: without 'allow_redirects=False' restriction ---\n")

url = 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg'
response = get_response(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 200)
case_2_comments()

print("\n\n--- Case 3: with 'allow_redirects=False' restriction ---\n")

url = 'http://photo.yupoo.com/evakicks/6b3a8a2a/small.jpg'
response = get_response_dont_redirect(url)
status = check_response_status(response)
save_image(response, 302)
case_3_comments()
```

Comment: What is the image in case 2 and 3 supposed to be of? The url requested in case 2 and 3 issues a redirect to the final url in case 2. That's why when allow_redirects is False, the status code is 302. Because the "final_url" is the url that tried to redirect you but failed due to the allow_redirects option.

Comment: In your case 2, if we open that link in a browser, it still redirects and opens http://adc.yupoo.com/res/703.gif. Thats what Python code is doing as well. What different behavior are you expecting?